# What are the kernels normally used in convolution neural network?

Tags: matlab, kernel, deep-learning, convolution

I am beginner in deep learning.I am using deep neural network [DNN] for image segmentation. I have few doubts. I have input image size 512x512.1. I want to select 6 Kernels of 5X5 pixels.I could not understand these kernels how I have to select, is there any standard kernel available? if yes please tell me.2. How can I take patch of a image? is it like manual cropping of some part from original image?

Comment: It actually depends on what tool/function/toolboxes are you using or you are planning to use. Any ideas about them? Also, have a look at Matlab Central, there are several home-made free toolboxes ready to use for CNN

Comment: I am using DNN toolbox(https://github.com/rasmusbergpalm/DeepLearnToolbox). In this case what will happen?

Comment: Yes, it's "manual cropping". Open Paint, select the crop tool and you are done :)

Comment: so conclusion is that, from the input image (size 512x512) I have to crop whole image manually for e.g. size of 32x32 like this and for all the images I have to run the DNN code separately? please tell me if i wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very good paper for CNN-based segmentation is "Fully Convolutional Networks for Semantic Segmentation" by J. Ling et al. and they released their pre-trained networks. They can be found in the [Caffe model zoo page](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Model-Zoo). They also released their code (in Caffe), so it is possible to train or fine-tune models on new segmentation problems.

Note that these models directly learn the "complete" segmentation of the images. They do not rely on sampled image patches with a single class as output like previous classification-based approaches.